# How can i make my Query faster using a Groupby with LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I created a Query, it is pretty fast but my table will have 100k+ or even a 1 million records. With 100k rows it takes 5s to load and that is to long. I know using `First()` is also querying, but I can't seem to find a way to not use it. I always get the same error when I try other things error:

> EF Core could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form
> that can be translated

```cs
public async Task<IEnumerable<TransactionLog>> GetUserTransactionHistory(string userId)
{
  var transactionLogs = await _context.TransactionLog
            .Where(t => t.UserId == userId)
            .GroupBy(log => log.CorrelationId)
            .Select(group => new TransactionLog
            {
                TransactionLogId = group.First().TransactionLogId,
                ChangeTimestamp = group.First().ChangeTimestamp,
                AutoDeleteTimestamp = group.First().AutoDeleteTimestamp,
                CorrelationId = group.Key,
                QueryResult = group.First().QueryResult,
                UserId = group.First().UserId,
                HasPreBackup = group.Any(t => t.BackupType == BackupType.PreBackup),
                HasPostBackup = group.Any(t => t.BackupType == BackupType.PostBackup)
            })
            .OrderByDescending(log => log.ChangeTimestamp)
            .ToListAsync();
  return transactionLogs;
}
```

This should return a list of `transactionlogs` grouped by the `correlationId`.

Comment: The Group is using a Hash Table and the hash is what is takes more time and you have larger inputs.  Also at end the ToListAsync() adds a lot of time to the code.  You are also quering a database (_context) and the query takes time.  When you have a large database to reduce time you should use the fastest machine you can get, and install as much memory that machine can hold.  Also make sure you put the database ins a tool like SQL Server that is meant for large databases, don't use excel.

Comment: The posted example code does not return transaction logs grouped by anything. It will only return one entity for each correlation Id, and most of its data will be from an arbitrary row within the group. But for some complicated queries you might just need to write the SQL by hand to get good performance.

Comment: So many `First`, without any `OrderBy`. What this query should do?

Answer (score 0):

It might be better if you select the `First` then pull out its properties afterwards.

```
var transactionLogs = await _context.TransactionLog
    .Where(t => t.UserId == userId)
    .GroupBy(log => log.CorrelationId)
    .Select(group => new {
        CorrelationId = group.Key,
        FirstValue = group.First(),
        HasPreBackup = group.Any(t => t.BackupType == BackupType.PreBackup),
        HasPostBackup = group.Any(t => t.BackupType == BackupType.PostBackup)
    })
    .Select(group => new TransactionLog
    {
        TransactionLogId = group.FirstValue.TransactionLogId,
        ChangeTimestamp = group.FirstValue.ChangeTimestamp,
        AutoDeleteTimestamp = group.FirstValue.AutoDeleteTimestamp,
        CorrelationId = group.CorrelationId,
        QueryResult = group.FirstValue.QueryResult,
        UserId = group.FirstValue.UserId,
        HasPreBackup = group.HasPreBackup,
        HasPostBackup = group.HasPostBackup
    })
    .OrderByDescending(log => log.ChangeTimestamp)
    .ToListAsync();
```

Note that `First()` by itself is non-deterministic. You probably want to `OrderBy` *within* each group also. Something like

```
        FirstValue = group.OrderByDescending(log => log.ChangeTimestamp).First(),
```

For this query to perform well, you are going to want something like the following index

```sql
TransactionLog (UserId, CorrelationId, ChangeTimestamp DESC)
  INCLUDE (BackupType, AutoDeleteTimestamp, QueryResult, TransactionLogId)
```